# How to monitoring MQPUT and MQGET?

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to monitoring the message of queue, how much producer message put and how much client has get message ? i saw in MQ Explorer and IBM MQ Web Console but it's just queue depth there is no queue message transaction put and get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "MQ Exit Programing". [here is official util](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24010343)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @TonyY i will try first

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the checkbox to accept it as the answer that help everyone can quickly find :>

Answer (score 0):

You need to either write your own MQ Monitoring tool or buy one (or use an open source one).  You can find a list of open source and commercial MQ Monitoring tools [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html).

Comment: Please advice for open source ?