# Monitoring MQGET

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

Is there any open-source tool or plugin to monitor MQGET calls?

More specifically we need to monitor Total MQGET operations on MQ Manager for some specific queues.

Checked the link provided with [How to monitoring MQPUT and MQGET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466495/how-to-monitoring-mqput-and-mqget) but dint find any.

Comment: I think we'd be able to answer better if we knew what you wanted to monitor about your MQGET calls. As noted in your link, API exits are one way, but they might be too much for what you need. What do you need to get out of this tool.

Comment: More specifically we need to monitor Total MQGET operations on MQ Manager for some specific queues.

Comment: What version of IBM MQ is the queue manager?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that immediately come to mind for monitoring the total number of MQGET operations on a queue.

1. RESET QSTATS
2. Queue Statistics

A comparison between these two methods is discussed [here](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2022/02/25/graphing-get-put-rates/). I won't repeat the whole post, but the pertinent comparison is thus.

| Reset QStats | Queue Statistics |
| --- | --- |
| Polls the Command Server. Care should be taken if you are monitoring large numbers of queues at high frequencies using this method because of the incurred load on the queue manager. However, for single queue high frequency graphs, this may be more suitable as you would you not likely want to set Accounting and Statistics intervals to really short timeframes, such as a minute or less. | Information is pushed by the Queue Manager as Accounting and Statistics messages, at configured intervals, and it therefore incurs less load on the queue manager. |
| Can only be consumed by one user as RESET QSTATS is destructive | Can be consumed by any number of users |
| Using RESET QSTATS will interfere with the collection of Performance Events | Using Queue Statistics does not interfere with any other data collection |
| Available on z/OS (turn on performance events to use it) and Distributed platforms | Only available on Distributed platforms, not on z/OS |
| Configuration is very simple to monitor a small number of queues, but becomes unwieldly to monitor many/all queues | Configuration requires a small amount of initial set up, but once set up, monitoring the entire queue manager is no more effort than monitoring a single queue |

Simple MQ Administrative tools usually have RESET QSTATS. You need something to process Accounting and Statistics messages if you want to use Queue Statistics.

Answer (score 0):

```
To monitor the total MQGET/MQPUT operations on MQ QMGR for specific queues, we can use amqsrua command by specifying the queue name.

**The usage of the command is as below:**

amqsrua [-m QMGR-NAME] [-c CLASS-NAME]
     [-o object name] [-t TYPE-NAME]
     [-p metadata prefix]
     [-n publication count]
     
Example: 

* To get MQGET Counts:
  amqsrua -m <QMGR Name> -c STATQ -t GET -o <Queue Name> -n1 

* To get MQPUT Counts:
  amqsrua -m <QMGR Name> -c STATQ -t PUT -o <Queue Name> -n1
```